# ArangoDB query returns extra items with diacritic marks

Tags: arangodb, diacritics

I have the question that is related to diacritic marks. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume, I have a document collection "c". I put two documents:

```
{"uri": "/c/de/aërotropismus/"}, {"uri": "/c/de/aerotropismus/"}
```

As you see, they are almost the same, except for the diacritic mark.

Then, I create a persistent index on the field "uri".

After this I do the query:

```
for doc in c
  filter doc.uri >= "/c/de/aerotropismus/" and doc.uri < "/c/de/aerotropismus0"
  return doc
```

I expect this query to return one result, but I get two results:

```
[
  {
    "_key": "37070873",
    "_id": "c/37070873",
    "_rev": "_bHsOMnm---",
    "uri": "/c/de/aerotropismus/"
  },
  {
    "_key": "37070853",
    "_id": "c/37070853",
    "_rev": "_bHsO_m6---",
    "uri": "/c/de/aërotropismus/"
  }
]
```

Why is that? And how can I fix it so that it returns just one result:

```
[
  {
    "_key": "37070873",
    "_id": "c/37070873",
    "_rev": "_bHsOMnm---",
    "uri": "/c/de/aerotropismus/"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed seems like a bug:

```
FOR doc IN c
    SORT doc.uri DESC
    RETURN KEEP(doc, ['uri'])
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "uri": "/c/de/aerotropismus/1"
  },
  {
    "uri": "/c/de/aërotropismus/"
  },
  {
    "uri": "/c/de/aerotropismus/"
  }
]
```

**Workaround**

You can create a user defined function inside ArangoDB to sort an array of strings.

More reading:

- [Registering an AQL user function](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/extending-functions.html#registering-an-aql-user-function)

**Workaround Implementation**

You can execute the following code in `aragosh` to register your custom function:

```js
const aqlfunctions = require("@arangodb/aql/functions");

function isBetween(elems, left, right) {
    const sorted = elems.sort();
    const leftIndex = sorted.findIndex((elem) => elem >= left);
    if (leftIndex === -1) {
        return [];
    }
    const rightIndexReversed = sorted.slice().reverse().findIndex((elem) => elem < right);
    if (rightIndexReversed === -1) {
        return [];
    }
    const rightIndex = sorted.length - rightIndexReversed - 1;
    if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
        return [];
    }
    return sorted.slice(leftIndex, rightIndex + 1);
}

aqlfunctions.register("CUSTOM::IS_BETWEEN", isBetween, true);
```

You can later run your AQL as this:

```
RETURN CUSTOM::IS_BETWEEN((FOR rec IN c RETURN rec.uri), "/c/de/aerotropismus/", "/c/de/aerotropismus0")
```

It will return only one record for the dataset you provided.

Comment: I've modified isBetween function to return documents instead of plain uris by calling `db.c.byExample` in a loop. I've profiled the resulting code by querying 100 uris. I've got the following results: 1.77 s for original code (with extra items with diacritics) and 4.87 for the workaround. I was dissatisfied with performance, so I wrote another workaround: I filtered the results on the Python side and I've got 1.91 s.

Comment: Have you also tried to profile a scenario where you add your original query as first argument of `CUSTOM:IS_BETWEEN` function? So you would put `(FOR doc IN c FILTER doc.uri >= "/c/de/aerotropismus/" and doc.uri < "/c/de/aerotropismus0" RETURN doc.uri)` as the first argument of my example. This should significantly lower down the number of `elems` passed into the custom function and hopefully improve the speed.

Comment: However, if filtering outside of arango works for you I would go that way.